# PHP class variable failing to update via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get some code to work for a uni assignment, I am still learning but feel like I'm going a little crazy trying to understand why a class variable is not working.

Using a PHP class such that

```
class Users {

    //Variables
    protected $_userName;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_login;
    protected $_firstName;
    protected $_lastName;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_phone;
    protected $_addressStreet;
    protected $_addressCity;
    protected $_addressState;
    protected $_company;

    public function __construct() {
       // gets the number of parameters
         $numArgs = func_num_args();
         $arg_list = func_get_args();
         // make decisions based on the arguments number
         switch($numArgs){
             case "2":return $this->ConstructorWithTwoArgs($arg_list[0], $arg_list[1]);
             case "10":return $this->ConstructorWithTenArgs($arg_list[0], $arg_list[1],$arg_list[2], $arg_list[3],$arg_list[4], $arg_list[5],$arg_list[6], $arg_list[7],$arg_list[8], $arg_list[9]);
             default:
                 //Handle exception for method not existing with that many parrams
                 break;
         }
    }
    //In order to log in we require minimum of user name and password
    protected function ConstructorWithTwoArgs($userName, $password){
        $this->_userName = $userName;
        $this->_password = $password;
        $this->_login = "false";
    return $this;
    }
    //Checks users details and updates user details if valid
    public function DoLogin(){
        $result = false;
        // Check if userName and password exist in the db
        $query = "SELECT * FROM SIT203Users WHERE USER_NAME = :userName AND PASSWORD = :password";
        // Create a new connection query
        $ds = new Connection();
        $ds->parse($query);
        $ds->setBindValue(':userName', $this->_userName);
        $ds->setBindValue(':password', $this->_password);
        $ds->execute();
        //User exists if rows are returned there will only be one as userName is unique
        if($ds->getNextRow()){            
            $result = true;
            $this->_login = "true";
            $this->_firstName = $ds->getRowValue("FIRST_NAME");
            $this->_lastName = $ds->getRowValue("LAST_NAME");
            $this->_email = $ds->getRowValue("EMAIL");
            $this->_phone = $ds->getRowValue("PHONE");
            $this->_addressStreet = $ds->getRowValue("ADDRESS_STREET");
            //Ensure all street details are obtained
            if($ds->getRowValue("ADDRESS_STREET2"))
                $this->_addressStreet .= $ds->getRowValue("ADDRESS_STREET2");
            $this->_addressCity = $ds->getRowValue("ADDRESS_CITY");
            $this->_addressState = $ds->getRowValue("ADDRESS_STATE");
            $this->_company = $ds->getRowValue("COMPANY"); 
    }

        $ds->freeResources();
        $ds->close();       
        return $result;     
    }
}
```

Now this class works fine for a direct call to it from;
http://www.deakin.edu.au/~jtparker/SIT203/xyz/flower_shop2/MyAccount.php?userName=JaieP&password=jp

```
<?php
require_once('initialise.php');

// Need to Validate all feilds and remove unwanted text
// The feilds to be tested are the $_REQUEST values
$userName = Validation::validateString(isset($_REQUEST['userName'])?$_REQUEST['userName']:"");
$password = Validation::validateString(isset($_REQUEST['password'])?$_REQUEST['password']:"");
$remberMe = isset($_REQUEST['remberMe'])?$_REQUEST['remberMe']:"";

// Create a new user
$newUser = new Users($userName, $password);
// Try and login
$newUser->DoLogin();
if($newUser->getLogin() == "true")
    {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $newUser;
    // Echo out the users details plus cart details for last 3 months

    //test its working to here
    //echo($newUser->toString());
    echo("Its working!!!");
}
else
    {
    //echo("falseValue");
    echo($userName.$password.$remberMe.$newUser->getLogin().$newUser->getUserName().$newUser->DoLogin().$newUser->toString());
}
?>
```

But when I try to use it via a javascript call using the below code the _login variable fails to update and for the life of me I can't work out why?
as can be seen from this link;
http://www.deakin.edu.au/~jtparker/SIT203/xyz/flower_shop2/myaccount.html
it fails every time?

Any ideas 
Many thanks in advance
Jaie

```
    function TryLogin(){    
    try{
        // Get the userName and password supplied
        var userName = document.getElementById( "userName" );
        var password = document.getElementById( "password" );

        // Get the remember me value
        var rememberMe = document.getElementById( "rememberMe" );

        // Get the error feild
        var errorDisplay =  document.getElementById( "submitError" );
        // set to no error
        errorDisplay.innerHTML = "";

        var documentMyAccount = document.getElementById( "myAccount" );

        // Submit details to server for verification if not empty
        if(userName.value != "" && password.value != ""){
            // Now check via DB if username and password are valid
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {   // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    // IF Response indicates a successful login
                    var myResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if(myResponse != "falseValue"){
                        // set to nothing
                        documentMyAccount.innerHTML = "";
                        // add php content
                        documentMyAccount.innerHTML = myResponse;
                    }
                    else{
                        // Do not advise what details are incorrect, just that some combination is incorrect
                        errorDisplay.innerHTML = "Sorry those details are not correct";
                    }
                }
            }
            var submitString = "MyAccount.php?";
            submitString +="userName="+userName.value;
            submitString +="&password="+password.value;
            submitString +="&rememberMe="+rememberMe.checked?"true":"false";
            xmlhttp.open("GET",submitString,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        else{
            errorDisplay.innerHTML = "Not all details have been entered!";
        }

    }
    catch(error){
        alert(error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(submitString)` just before your `xmlhttp.open`call?

Comment: Awesome see your point, I think that the problem GET /~jtparker/SIT203/xyz/flower_shop2/MyAccount.php?userName=JaieP&password=jptrue Place an answer and will mark you right cause you nailed it, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to debug what's the final URL that is being called by your AJAX and confirm if everything is being sent as you expect and that will solve it.

Try

```
console.log(submitString)
```

before your AJAX call and you'll know if everything is being sent correctly.